# How can I add routes to my React app server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I set just set up a React app using the tutorial on [React Tutorials Page](https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#creating-a-new-application). To run the application I type `npm start`.

Package.json mentions that start should run `react-scripts start`. I am trying to understand where the server lives on this application. I want to add routes on this so that I can implement some backend functionality to make AJAX calls to '/email' or similar path.

I am new to React but I am assuming there should be some Express routing that is listening on the port. If not, what do I need to understand about the architecture?

Answer (score 2):

You can see what the start script does [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js). It is serving your app with [webpack dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/). If you want to use express, then you will need to set up your own express server.

You can [proxy requests through the dev server](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) to help with cors issues

Comment: So if I have to put my code to Production now with an express server what would be the correct approach? Will I need to modify the react-scripts node module?

Comment: npm start is just for development, for production you would serve the compiled app, Read through the create-react-app docs (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)